# How do I set an environment variable from Windows Command Prompt by way of a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, environment-variables

I wrote this simple PowerShell script (`setJava.ps1`), to be able to quickly switch java versions:

```
$version = $args[0]
$scriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand

if($version -eq $null){
    echo "Usage: .\${$scriptName} <version>"
    exit
}

echo "Searching for jdk-${version}..."

[array]$dirs = Get-ChildItem *$version* | select -expand fullname

if($dirs.Length -eq 0){
    echo "Path for 'jdk-${version}' not found..."
    exit
}

if($dirs.Length -gt 1){
    echo "Found more than one 'jdk-${version}'! Try a more specific version (e.g '.\${scriptName} ${version}.1')"
    exit
}

echo "Found in path '$dirs'"

$env:JAVA_HOME = $dirs
$env:Path = "$env:JAVA_HOME\bin;$env:Path"
echo "Java ${version} temporarily activated for this session."
```

I also added simple Batch file (`powershell setJava.ps1`) which I added to Path, to be able to switch it also in normal Windows command line, but java version does not get changed in this command line.

Am I able to set environment variables for normal Command Line from PowerShell script?

PS: I used Powershell, because Batch is so stupidly hard to work with...

Comment: When you run `powershell setJava.ps1` from cmd.exe, the environment variables get updated in the powershell.exe process that runs the script. When that powershell.exe process terminates, the variables in its environment block are not propagated back to the parent process (i.e., the cmd.exe instance that invoked powershell.exe).

Comment: to set environment vars for something _other than the current process_, you likely otta use `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` with the `machine` target option.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart thanks for explanation of something I know :D I need solution, not explanation :)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey but then they are persisted right?

Comment: @Baterka - yes, they are persistent ... that is what you seem to want. [*grin*] ///// options for _semi-demi-persitance_ ... **_[A]_** clear the setting after you are finished with it. **_[B]_** use a file to transfer the info between processes. **_[C]_** use a thread-safe object type like the `synchronous` types here >>> Synchronizing Data for Multithreading | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/synchronizing-data-for-multithreading **_[D]_** there are likely even more. [*grin*]

Comment: Describing why helps to lead to solutions. A possible solution for your use case is to write the environment variables to a temporary .cmd script and then run that.